# cycloneDx Bom is not fetching all dependencies of my project

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-management

cycloneDx Bom is  not fetching all dependencies of my project, how to fetch all dependencies through  cycloneDx bom.

I run the command to create bom it's fetching only few dependencies the command i used '.\dotnet-CycloneDX.exe D:\Folder_Project\Project.sln -r -o c:\binaries\output\DevExpT'.

Comment: please refer to the project's support channel: https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-dotnet/issues